# Problem of using arabtex in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, arabtex

I have problems using `arabtex` in `memoir`. Since I don't really know where the problems lie I will just paste the code as minimal as i could. So, here are my codes.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum,suffix,fbb}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{headings}{%
 \def\chaptermark##1{% 
  \markboth{\MakeLowercase{%
   \ifnum\c@secnumdepth > \m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
     {\scshape\@chapapp}\ {\oldstylenums{\thechapter}}. \ %
    \fi
   \fi
   {\scshape ##1}}}{}}}

\newcommand{\printchapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
    {\hskip1.5em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize\normalsize#1}{}{}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip0pt}%
}  
\makeatother

\newcommand\chapterauthor[1]{\authortoc{#1}\printchapterauthor{#1}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\chapterauthor*[1]{\printchapterauthor{#1}}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{headings}

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapterauthor{bertrand einstein}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

There are no problems with these codes until I've inserted `\tableofcontents` after the `\frontmatter`. It will render my Texmaker indefinitely.

But the problems will be OK again once I removed `\chapterauthor{bertrand einstein}`. That's what I've got so far. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have texmaker, but there is also a problem with your file when running TeX from the command line.

Add the line

```
\let\notr@ce\relax\let\dotr@ce\relax
```

before `\makeatother`.

`arabtex.sty` contains debugging code that breaks when written to the toc file. The two `\let` statements disable the macros for switching tracing on/off. As long as you don't want to debug arabtex.sty, this should be no problem.

Does this solve your problem?